# How to add `--flag value` conditionally based on a parameter in a Makefile target command?

Tags: bash, makefile

Consider 2 makefile target triggers:

```
make print  # Print everything
```

```
make print filter=topic-a  # Print only topic-a
```

Now, inside Makefile target, the `filter` functionality is realised via some command's flag, like this:

```
print:
  some_command --arg --anotherarg \
    --filter <filter>
```

In some cases, the command doesn't handle an **empty** `--filter` very well, so the question is..

#### Question

How to add/remove `--filter <filter` conditionally inside Makefile target based on whether the param has been passed to the `make` itself (`make print filter=topic-a`)?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with `make` functions for conditionals (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html):

```sh
print:
  some_command --arg --anotherarg \
    $(if $(filter),--filter $(filter),)
```

An inline conditional expression works like this:

```
$(if condition,then-part[,else-part])
```

Note how the `condition` is evaluated:

> If it expands to any non-empty string, then the condition is considered to be true. If it expands to an empty string, the condition is considered to be false.